# Changing an attribute after transition

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to change certain attribute transitionally while changing another attribute instantly when the transition is completed?

I want to change the `height` of an element transitionally from `0` to `100%`. When the `height` is `0`, I want its `overflow` to be `hidden`, and when the `height` reaches `100%`, I want its `overflow` to become `auto`.

I tried this:

```
#foo{
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.25s;
}

#foo.some-state{
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

This causes strange effect. If the final state ends up with enough height so that there is no need of a scroll bar, what happens is that the scroll bar is first absent at `height: 0`. Then it appears when the transition starts, and sustains during transition while the height is not enough. When the height becomes sufficient, then the scroll bar disappears once again.

In such case, I want the scroll bar to not appear during transition. In other words, I want `overflow` to switch from `hidden` to `auto` when transition is completed. How can this be done?

Comment: That’s not possible via a CSS transition alone. There’s the `transitionend` event that allows you to react to it with JS. If you want to do it without that, you could set `overflow:scroll` instead, so that a scrollbar appears from the very beginning. Using an animation instead of a transition might be another way.

Comment: @CBroe I will accept that as an answer if you make it so.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I just happened to see that. It's good that you are participating. I also enjoy proposing things there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s not possible via a CSS transition alone. If you wan to use nothing else, you could set `overflow:scroll` instead, so that a scrollbar appears from the very beginning.

There’s the [`transitionend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) event that allows you to react to the end of the transition with JS. So with a small little handler function you could add the `overflow:auto` (or set a class to that effect) only then.

Using an [animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) instead of a transition might be another way. You will need to specify the `overflow` in every single keyframe, because `overflow` is a property that can’t be interpolated and as such would be dropped from the animation entirely otherwise.